# Allow redirect to URL not within htdocs (XAMPP)

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect, xampp

really struggling to allow my form to allow users to access a URL depending on what radio button they select. When I complete the form on my server, it does the redirect to the dedicated URL as expected however, it says the object can't be found and also says "The requested URL was not found on this server." I don't really understand how I would save a file to the htdocs folder for a URL of a website. The website options that the user could potentially be redirected to are the following:

http://www.nisra.gov.uk/demography/default.asp28.htm

http://www.nrscotland.gov.uk/statistics-and-data/statistics/statistics-by-theme/vital-events/names/babies-first-names

http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/rel/vsob1/baby-names--england-and-wales/index.html

The following is what I have for my code:

PHP:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['location']))
  {

$location = $_GET["location"];

if ($location === "S"){

header("Location:  http://www.nrscotland.gov.uk/statistics-and-data/statistics/statistics-by-theme/vital-events/names/babies-first-names");

}   else if ($location === "EW")

{
header("Location: http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/rel/vsob1/baby-names--england-and-wales/index.html");

}   else if ($location === "NI")

{
header("Location: http://www.nisra.gov.uk/demography/default.asp28.htm");

}

}

?>
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Baby Name Popularity Tables</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Baby Name Popularity Tables</h1>
Please select either England and Wales, Scotland or Northern Ireland.
<form action="" method="get">
<table>
<tr> 
<td><input type="radio" name="location" value="EW"/></td>
<td>England &amp; Wales</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="location" value="S"/></td>
<td>Scotland</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="location" value="NI"/></td>
<td>Northern Ireland</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Get Baby Names"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>     
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first of all, you should refactory your code, to be more clean and precise, for this, I did for you, but try to improve next time :)

**redirectForm.php**

```
<?php

$websites = [
    "S" => "http://www.nrscotland.gov.uk/statistics-and-data/statistics/statistics-by-theme/vital-events/names/babies-first-names",
    "EW" => "http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/rel/vsob1/baby-names--england-and-wales/index.html",
    "NI" => "http://www.nisra.gov.uk/demography/default.asp28.htm",
    // "ANOTHER_PLACE" => "WEBSITE",
    // "ANOTHER_PLACE" => "WEBSITE",
];

$location = isset($_GET['location']) ? $_GET['location'] : false;

foreach ($websites as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === $location) {
        header("Location: ".$value);
    }
}
```

HTML (note what I did on form action, line 8):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Baby Name Popularity Tables</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Baby Name Popularity Tables</h1>
Please select either England and Wales, Scotland or Northern Ireland.
<form action="redirectForm.php" method="get">
<table>
<tr> 
<td><input type="radio" name="location" value="EW"/></td>
<td>England &amp; Wales</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="location" value="S"/></td>
<td>Scotland</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="location" value="NI"/></td>
<td>Northern Ireland</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Get Baby Names"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but this also doesn't work. It does the exact same where it successfully redirects the user to the dedicated URL but the object can't be found. Not sure what is causing the problem tbh